# AWS EB deploy fails: npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to circumvent the well-known issue with the latest versions of NPM and AWS Elastic Beanstalk where *npm install* fails because it can't find *node_modules*. I'm using platform hooks with my NUXTJS application.

It fails when AWS Code Pipeline runs a deploy and returns with this warning:

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app- 
deploy] - [Use NPM to install dependencies]. Stop running the 
command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c npm --production install 
failed with error signal: killed. Stderr:npm WARN config 
production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

So, I've added platform hooks at the app root but it's still failing. Also, I have added an environment variable to the EBS environment of:

```
NODE_ENV=production
```

Here's what my platform hooks look like. I thought this would work but something is obviously wrong. Can anyone spot it? Thanks for any helpful tips.

[image]

The *custom-prebuild-script.sh* looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

`NPM_USE_PRODUCTION = false`

in environment variables